# Reach to LAN device from a different subnet

Tags: router, subnet, bridge

I have my network configured this way:

The ISP router giving internet access (192.168.**1**.1/24) through wifi (SSID wlan01).

Connected to this wifi I have a Nanostation2 (192.168.**0**.20/24) in bridge mode.

Finally I have a neutral router connected to the Nanostation2 in the WAN port.
The WAN port is configured as DHCP auto (so the ISP router gives the neutral router a 192.168.**1**.X/24 address).

This neutral router has a subnet (192.168.**10**.0/24), it's configured as a DHCP server (192.168.**10**.1/24) and provides another wifi connection (SSID wlan02).

I need to connect with the Nanostation2 (192.168.**0**.20) while I am connected to the wlan02 SSID, which gives me an 192.168.**10**.X IP address to my computer's wireless interface...

Is this possible through a static routing entry or with another method?

Comment: If you provide some picture or diagram about your network, will be useful. Also, one question: how do you connect to your nanostation to the 192.168.0.20/24 address??, do you connected with a cable??, do you configure your PC with an address on 192.168.0.0/24??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused about where the `192.168.0.0/24` network is defined. If the Nanostation is in bridge mode it should have an IP address on the network `192.168.1.0/24`.

Your "neutral router" will have a default route to the ISP, and it will send anything from its LAN port to the default route. It doesn't know where the `192.168.0.0/24` network is. Conversely, the Nanostation should have a route to the `192.168.10.0/24` network is unless the "neutral router" is running NAT (giving you double-NAT which is probably not a good idea).

You can do this with static routes, which doesn't scale, or a routing protocol between routers.

Comment: The 192.168.0.0/24 network is not defined. It's only that the Nanostation is configured with the static IP address 192.168.0.20.

Comment: You can't just assign an address to a host which doesn't belong to any network and hope it works. You should have the Nanostation get its address from the network which it bridges. That will probably fix everything.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Configuring the Nano to an 192.168.1.X static IP address solves all my problems! Thank you!!! :))))